# why is type of 'false' is int? (CS50)

Tags: c, cs50

> I would like to exit the program when my argv[1] contains some character other than alphabet. Therefore, I stated:

```
for(int j = 0, p = strlen(argv[1]); j < p; j++)
    {
        if (false(isalpha(argv[1][j])))
        {
            printf("invalid character\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

> but it says error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer. I don't understand what this means. This was from the CS50 week2's problem - substitution.

Comment: What type did you expect and why? Are you looking for `if (!isalpha(...))`?

Comment: You may want `!` instead of `false`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil summarized it nicely in his reply!  On a side (but irrelevant) note, `argv` always points to `nul`-terminated char-buffers, so there's no need to use `strlen()` at all in this case, and the code may be simplified to: `for (char *cp=argv[1]; *cp; cp++) { if (!isalpha(*cp)) {puts("invalid character"); return1;} }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in function named `false` in C. Your expression `false(isalpha(argv[1][j]))` has the form `false(x)`, so it looks like a function call.

The header `<stdbool.h>` defines a macro that expands to an integer constant zero. So `false(x)` is effectively `0(x)`. In this, `0` is an `int` constant. The compiler message “called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer” is telling you that you cannot call this `int` `0` as if it were a function.

If you have some function in your program named `false`, it may have been effectively overridden by including `<stdbool.h>` (or possibly some other header file). If so, you should rename your function.

To test whether an expression is “false,” you can use the `!` operator:

```
if (!isalpha(argv[1][j]))
{
    // Code here will be executed when isalpha(argv[1][j]) is false.
}
```